# How to pass a vaulted yml-file as extra vars?

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault, ansible-pull

Couldn't find anything about this. I need to pass a vaulted variable file as extra vars, i.e.:

```
ansible-pull -U <URL> -f -C master -d <ROLE_PATH> -i hosts --clean --vault-id <VAULT-ID/PW-FILE> -e @<VAULTED-VAR-FILE>
```

Seems like it cannot find the vaulted file..

```
ansible 2.9.10



config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']

  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible

  executable location = /bin/ansible

  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:16:51) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]

Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

Parsed localhost, inventory source with host_list plugin

ERROR! Attempting to decrypt but no vault secrets found
```

Note: If I decrypt the vaulted file, it will run.

Did anyone run into the same problem or know a solution?

Thansk and best regards

Comment: Did you use a specific vault-id while encrypting the file or the default one? In case of specific vault-id, the syntax is `--vault-id <VAULT_ID>@<PW_FILE>`, and for default it's simply `--vault-id @<PW_FILE>`

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"ERROR! Attempting to decrypt but no vault secrets found"*

A: The error is clear. Provide ansible-pull with the [vault secret](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#ansible-vault).

But, this would require making the vault secret available on the remote host, running ansible-pull, in plain-text. This is a pretty weak solution from a security standpoint. Use it in a secure environment only. Otherwise, I'd recommend using the push model to manage secrets.

---

Alternative solution

If you really need to manage secrets on the remote-hosts by ansible-pull you might want to store the secrets in [passwordstore](https://www.passwordstore.org/) and use Ansible lookup plugin [passwordstore](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/passwordstore.html#passwordstore-manage-passwords-with-passwordstore-org-s-pass-utility) to retrieve secrets.

- passwordstore uses gpg
- gpg is the best choice open-source cryptographic software suite
- instead of vault secrets maintain the gpg keys at the remote hosts
- [run gpg-agent](https://ansible-runner-role.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#run-gpg-agent)
- passwordstore stores the encrypted files in git
- clone/pull the passwordstore git repo to the remote-host before running ansible-pull